# SQL. Make a request to get a rating of goods

Tags: mysql, sql

Good afternoon, there are 2 tables. One with the product, the other with the quantity of the ordered product and the order number. Help me compose a skl query, where I would display a match (id product = quantity of ordered product), provided that there may be several records in the table with the same product. They need to be summed up somehow.

id tovara = id product

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geQs3.png)

Comment: Including the CREATE TABLE statements along with some example data and your expected output will be more likely to get a response. Searching for JOIN and GROUP BY on here will return numerous examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT p.product_name, SUM(o.quantity)
FROM products p
INNER JOIN orders o
    ON p.product_id = o.product_id
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved by including some explanation of how it works so that the OP can learn.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica Very true but given the lack of detail provided in the question and that two people had already voted to close the question I thought I did well to provide an answer at all. Feel free to provide a more detailed answer.